# TigerVNC Cinnamon session on Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, x11, vnc, cinnamon

I'm trying to properly start a Cinnamon (2D) session in `tigervnc-server` on Fedora 17 "Beefy Miracle". The only way I currently know to accomplish this is to modify the file `/etc/X11/xinit/Xclients`. The first line originally looks like this:

```
GSESSION="$(type -p gnome-session)"
```

and I'm changing it to

```
GSESSION="$(type -p gnome-session-cinnamon2d)"
```

The problem with this approach is, that this change is reverted if the `xorg-x11-xinit` package is updated, which already happened to me.

Is there a better way to do this, without having to reset it each time I update my system?